# Why is javascript "apply" on $.extend and array of one element returns the element combined with Window object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are the values I get when array has 3 elements and 1 element respectively:

```
$.extend.apply(this,[{a:"b"},{a:"c"},{a:"d"}])
Object {a: "d"}

$.extend.apply(this,[{a:"b"}])
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

The first is as expected, but for second I was expecting

```
Object {a: "b"}
```

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `this` is refering to the `window` object. Try this: `(function(){return this;})();` on your console.

Comment: The second one is like calling `$.extend({a : "b"})`, and when only one argument is passed, you're extending jQuery, as there is no target passed in. It's done this way because `$.extend` also is an easy way to extend the jQuery namespace.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Note that `this` isn't being used as an argument to `extend` - it's an argument to `apply`, setting the context for `this` _within_ `extend`. According to the docs, it should be extending the jQuery namespace, not `window`

Comment: thisArg is the first argument of apply. For this case I think it shouldn't matter as all it does is set the value of this inside $.extend to Window. I dont think its because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` accepts two arguments, the first is the `this` value, the second is an array containing the arguments to pass.

If you forget about the `this` value, which isn't really important here at all, what you're doing is

```
$.extend({a:"b"}, {a:"c"}, {a:"d"});

$.extend({a:"b"});
```

All you have to do to figure this out, is read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

> ```
> jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )
> ```
>
> An object that will receive the new properties if additional objects
>   are passed in **or that will extend the jQuery namespace if it is the**
>   **sole argument.**

So basically your second example just extends the jQuery namespace

```
$.extend({a:"b"});
console.log( $.a ); // returns "b"
```

You just added `a` to `jQuery`

When using `$.extend` the regular way, like above, it returns `jQuery`, so it can be chained.

```
$.extend({a:"b"}).extend({c:"d"});
```

but when called with `apply` and setting the `this` value to the window, it returns the window instead.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I couldn't get - the fact that because there is no target, it would just be returning `this`.  I figured it would still be returning the modified object.

Comment: I could probably be a little clearer on that, I'll add something to the answer.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure that the behaviour is right.  [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/3h8gwdpg/).  In theory, there's still only 1 argument to `extend`, yet it seems like if you set the `this` context to _anything_ other than `window`, jQuery will extend it, rather than itself.  And it's returning the modified object, rather than the window now.

Comment: Ah - I guess usually `extend` would probably have `this` set as the jQuery object itself.  By overriding it to be something different, is probably what's causing what I'm seeing

Comment: @JamesThorpe - indeed, looking at the source, if `arguments.length === 1` jQuery does something else, it extend whatever `this` is, assuming it would always be jQuery, as `$.extend` would always be called that way, not with another `this` value. So when changing the `this` value, whatever `this` is, is extended instead, so long as it's an object or function (jQuery checks that as well.)